Rsync error. Specified method is not supported. Visual Studio 2022 community remote debug
I want to debug my project, which uses CMake. I have a virtual machine (ubuntu) and I am using Connection Manager in VS2022 to connect to my machine by ssh. The connection is successful, but when I wanted to build my project, I got this error. I have no clue what's wrong. Can somebody help me fix the problem or suggest a direction on where to go to fix it?
log:
1> [CMake] -- Generating done (0.1s)
1> [CMake] -- Build files have been written to: /home/...
1> Extracted CMake variables.
1> Extracted source files and headers.
1> Extracted code model.
1> Extracted toolchain configurations.
1> Extracted includes paths.
1> Specified method is not supported.
Specified method is not supported.
   at liblinux.IO.Rsync.PrepareForDirectorySync(Int32 sessionID, IReadOnlyCollection`1 paths, RsyncDirection direction, RemoteRsyncDaemon daemon, String[] daemonOptions, Int32 localPort, RsyncVerbosity verbosity, Boolean recursive, IReadOnlyCollection`1 includes, IReadOnlyCollection`1 excludes, String customOptions)
   at liblinux.IO.Rsync.<SyncDirectoriesAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at liblinux.IO.Rsync.<SyncDirectoriesAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Linux.Project.CMakeLinuxHeadersUpdateTask.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<<UpdateHeaders>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Linux.Project.CMakeLinuxHeadersUpdateTask.UpdateHeaders(CMakeConfiguration config, IBuildProject project, String[] projectIncludes, String[] projectExcludes, String[] projectDownloads, Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Linux.Project.RemoteCMakeParser.<AfterParseAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Linux.Project.RemoteCMakeParser.<ParseAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Project.ExternalBuildProject.ProjectProvider.<ParseProjectAsync>d__46.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Project.ExternalBuildProject.ProjectProvider.<ParseProjectAsync>d__46.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.ExternalBuildFramework.Impl.ParseCache.<ParseAsyncImpl>d__34.MoveNext()```

I updated the rsync version on my machine, but it doesn't work.


Here is a similar ticket that may  help.

The problem was that CMake generated a very long string with several paths and these paths, as I understand it, were passed to the PrepareForDirectorySync method. Due to the very large length of the string, the PrepareForDirectorySync method returned an error and stopped the build.

Glad to hear you have found the root cause of this issue. You may be interested in this.BTW, you can add your solution to an answer ,this will help other users who has the same issue find the solution easily. Just a reminder.

Okay, I'll take a look. Thanks for the advice.

The problem was that CMake generated a very long string with several paths and these paths, as I understand it, were passed to the PrepareForDirectorySync method. Due to the very large length of the string, the PrepareForDirectorySync method returned an error and stopped the build.
